# Baby Rudin: showing continuity without Lebesgue dominated convergence and ACC?

Tags: real-analysis

Exercise #12, p.333 of Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* 3rd edition is bugging me.

The solution is straightforward in the way he (presumably) intended, but I wonder about solving it without using Lebesgue Dominated Convergence and Countable Choice.

Here's the problem:

> Let $\left|f(x, y)\right| \le 1$ when $0 \le x \le 1$ and $0 \le y \le1$.
>   Assume that $f$ is continuous $x$ (for fixed $y$) and $y$ (for fixed $x$) individually, without assuming it's jointly continuous in $(x, y)$.
>   Put $$g(x) = \int_0^1 f(x, y)\ dy$$
>   Show $g$ is continuous.

The problem is from the (seldom read?) Chapter 11 of the book.

If all you want to show is sequential continuity, then all you have to do is apply Lebesgue Dominated Convergence.

Is there a way to show usual "$\epsilon$ - $\delta$" continuity without invoking Countable Choice?

Comment: Is f nonnegative?

Comment: Yes for sure... thanks, I made an edit.

Comment: Actually, $f$ just needs to be bounded.